# iPhone - application displays a blank screen when loaded on a real device (sometimes)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, application-settings

I currently have an iPhone application that runs fine on the simulator and also runs fine on a real device when it is connected to the Mac and is attached to the Xcode debugger.

I can close the app and open it again no problem.

However when I remove the device from the mac usb and try to use my application normally it sometimes tries to load and gets stuck on a blank black screen. Other times it will load normally and if I press the home button and launch the app again it usually launches fine.

The device is setup for debugging and I simply place the app on it by running it on Xcode, so is this my problem? Do I need to change the apps settings to get it to run on the device without this issue to a release version or something along those lines?

EDIT:

I have some additional info that seems to reproduce it everytime.

It happens if I push my app to the background by pressing the home button, then I leave the device lying there for around 5 minutes and when I click on the icon to launch my app again I see my app for a split second and then its a black screen

Comment: Yes I have a Default.png, it sometimes gets stuck on it as well but mostly just shows a black screen

Comment: Of course, when you push the app to the background it's not ended, and tapping its icon causes it to be resumed.  Exactly how iOS handles this I've never quite deciphered, but I suspect that iOS has, in the failing case, decided to "unload" some of your loaded views, and on reloading them something goes sour.  Unfortunately, hard/impossible to reproduce with the debugger on, to my knowledge.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce a "SIGPIPE" error while debugging, could that cause the symptoms experienced when not connected to the debugger?

Comment: Are you doing a lot of work in the UIApplicationDelegate methods that are related to launching and becoming active?

Comment: Very little, currently I'm only logging one line in applicationdidenterbackground and applicationdidenterforeground and only launching a view in applicationdidfinishlaunching.